# StMoMo package and boostrap function

Tags: r

I'm using the `R` package `StMoMo` on mortality data, but I'm having some problem to understand the bootstrap procedure. As I catched, the function `boostrap` allows to create bootstrap parameters in order to take into account the uncertainty from them (because it's not easy compute the model uncertainty with classical way). After obtained `nBoot` bootstrap samples, the `simulate` function has to be used, in order to sample from the boostrapped parameters and forecast. In the list of arguments of this function there is `nsim`, that is the number of sample paths to generate from boostrapped parameters but in the package vignette, Villegas et al. haven't used the argument nsim, meaning that only 1 sample has been generated from each bootstrapped parameter. So, is it correct increase the number of sample in order to have a better confidence interval? Below two different result fixing `nBoot`to 100 and varying `nsim` from 1 to 100.

[100 bootstrap with `nsim` = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EucOT.png)

[100 bootstrap with `nsim` = 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8mZL.png)

As we can see in the second pic confidence interval seems to be better than in the first one (well the aim should to build confidence interval that include the red point). My question could be a little confusing, but anyway what is the correct number of simulation from `n` bootstrap samples? Thank you